# APM,IAsyncResult Model (Server-Side) database async call vs. threadpool use

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

This question deals with AMP (.Net < 4.5) Please don`t propose me to use TAP.I know about it.
But try to understand what is correct way for such implementation and waht is going in the CLR.
I have the following implementation for  Squrare Root

```
public IAsyncResult BeginGetSquareRoot(double value, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        GetSquareRootAsyncResult asyncResult =
            new GetSquareRootAsyncResult(callback, state);
        asyncResult.Value = value;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            new WaitCallback((Callback)),
            asyncResult);

        return asyncResult;
    }
```

Now I want to implement other async call for some Stored Procedure execution
Should I also use Thread Pool with Callback.Or can I just call `BeginExecuteReader(AsyncCallback callback, object stateObject);`
Or(if I don`t use ThreadPool)it may just open too much threads and stuck the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the thread-pool for database work is the well-known async-over-sync anti-pattern. Use async IO throughout. Use `BeginExecuteReader` because that will not keep a thread blocked. It does not require a thread while it runs.

Comment: So,while BeginExecuteReader runs it doesn`t allocate other thread?What happens if the server gets the query from other clien?How that client will not be blocked?

Comment: >>Using the thread-pool for database work is the well-known async-over-sync anti-pattern - can you please explain the reason for that?Thx

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx. Speaks in terms of TPL, but applies to all async IO. Async IO does not need threads. It's just data structures in the CLR and the kernel. The hardware initiates the callback using interrupts.

Comment: Thank you very much.Can you please explain me when should I use ThreadPool and when not (for async - over - sync)?In this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx - they advice to use ThreadPool

Comment: Use the thread pool for CPU bound work, not for IO. Using threads for IO and exposing an async interface to callers is async-over-sync. Almost never makes sense. BeginGetSquareRoot seems to be such a case as well.; Btw, in all of this I have assumed that you *must* use IAsyncResult. It is obsolete as of .NET 4.